# How to add transitive dependencies in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

**Background**

I have a project on my old machine that runs Android studio 2.2.2 and Gradle 2.1.4.
I now have a new machine with the latest or a more later version of android studio (3.2) and gradle 4.3.

My original project was using compilesdkVersion 23 and had GCM integrated. I now have a new machine and want to update my IDE and dependencies to the latest, so that i can integrate FireBase and use runtime permissions. I decided to do all this on a new machine as my software is in production on 8000 devices and didn't want to break my production build.

**The problem**

My new project is using compileSdkVersion 28 and buildToolsVersion '28.0.0' but i'm getting the following build error:

```
Could not find com.android.support:mediarouter:28.0.0.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Users/MatthewW/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/mediarouter/28.0.0/mediarouter-28.0.0.pom
    file:/C:/Users/MatthewW/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/mediarouter/28.0.0/mediarouter-28.0.0.jar
    file:/C:/Users/MatthewW/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/mediarouter/28.0.0/mediarouter-28.0.0.pom
    file:/C:/Users/MatthewW/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/mediarouter/28.0.0/mediarouter-28.0.0.jar
    file:/C:/Users/MatthewW/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/mediarouter/28.0.0/mediarouter-28.0.0.pom
    file:/C:/Users/MatthewW/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/mediarouter/28.0.0/mediarouter-28.0.0.jar
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/mediarouter/28.0.0/mediarouter-28.0.0.pom
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/mediarouter/28.0.0/mediarouter-28.0.0.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/mediarouter/28.0.0/mediarouter-28.0.0.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/mediarouter/28.0.0/mediarouter-28.0.0.jar
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/mediarouter/28.0.0/mediarouter-28.0.0.pom
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/mediarouter/28.0.0/mediarouter-28.0.0.jar
Required by:
    project :app

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
Open Android SDK Manager
```

I have installed the Android support Repository

[image]

Also, in my build.gradle file, in the dependencies, the appCompat 28.0.0 is underlined in red. When i hover over it, it states that all Android support libraries must use the exact same version specification. i have specified 28.0.0 but it has found a transitive dependency 24.0.0 (mediarouter), i'm sure there will be others.

[image]

To find all the transitive dependencies i followed this post by cricket_007:

[transitive dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWKOM.png)

I cant post the output as it exceed the 30000 char limit on StackOverflow, but below is an except that shows the mediarouter is v24.

```
Executing tasks: [androidDependencies]

Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
The CompileOptions.bootClasspath property has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the CompileOptions.bootstrapClasspath property instead.
:app:androidDependencies
debug
debugCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
+--- C:\Users\MatthewW\AndroidStudioProjects\nfcscanner3\app\libs\activation.jar
+--- C:\Users\MatthewW\AndroidStudioProjects\nfcscanner3\app\libs\additionnal.jar
+--- C:\Users\MatthewW\AndroidStudioProjects\nfcscanner3\app\libs\core.jar
+--- C:\Users\MatthewW\AndroidStudioProjects\nfcscanner3\app\libs\mail.jar
+--- C:\Users\MatthewW\AndroidStudioProjects\nfcscanner3\app\libs\ndeftools-1.2.3.jar
+--- C:\Users\MatthewW\AndroidStudioProjects\nfcscanner3\app\libs\gcm.jar
+--- com.android.support:design:28.0.0@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:9.8.0@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:9.8.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:24.0.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0@aar
```

When i clean the project i get the following (i had to split the screen one under the other as they were to small):

[image]
[image]

In the above screen shot it states:

```
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to execute aapt
```

I've read that this can be some problem with the resources and long names or special chars in the name.

Has anyone any ideas on how i can get this project building with no errors?

[EDIT 1]
here is my build.gradle

```
> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
> 
> android {
>     compileSdkVersion 28
>     buildToolsVersion '28.0.0'
> 
> 
>     useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
> 
>     lintOptions {
>         checkReleaseBuilds false
>         // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
>         // but continue the build even when errors are found:
>         abortOnError false
>     }
> 
>     defaultConfig {
>         applicationId "com.xxxx"
>         minSdkVersion 16
>         targetSdkVersion 28
>         versionName "5.1"
>         setProperty("archivesBaseName", "RR4v$versionName")
>     }
> 
>     buildTypes {
>         release {
>             minifyEnabled true
>             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
>         }
>     } }
> 
> dependencies {
>     compile files('libs/activation.jar')
>     compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
>     compile files('libs/core.jar')
>     compile files('libs/mail.jar')
>     compile files('libs/ndeftools-1.2.3.jar')
>     compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
>     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
>     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
>     compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.1'
>     compile 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.6@aar'
>     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
>     compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
>     compile 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
> 
> 
> }
```

[EDIT2]

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    compile files('libs/core.jar')
    compile files('libs/mail.jar')
    compile files('libs/ndeftools-1.2.3.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.1'
    implementation 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.6@aar'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

[EDIT3]

```
C:\Users\MatthewW\AndroidStudioProjects\nfcscanner3>gradlew clean :app:processDebugResources

> Configure project :app 
Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
The CompileOptions.bootClasspath property has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the CompileOptions.bootstrapClasspath property instead.

C:\Users\MatthewW\AndroidStudioProjects\nfcscanner3\app\src\main\res\layout\drop_down_list_row.xml:7: AAPT: error: '@+DropDownList/checkbox' is incompatible with attribute id (attr) reference.

C:\Users\MatthewW\AndroidStudioProjects\nfcscanner3\app\src\main\res\layout\drop_down_list_row.xml:12: AAPT: error: '@+DropDownList/SelectOption' is incompatible with attribute id (attr) reference.

C:\Users\MatthewW\AndroidStudioProjects\nfcscanner3\app\src\main\res\layout\messagerecipientlayout.xml:15: AAPT: error: '@+DropDownList/SelectBox' is incompatible with attribute id (attr) reference.

C:\Users\MatthewW\AndroidStudioProjects\nfcscanner3\app\src\main\res\layout\messagerecipientlayout.xml:25: AAPT: error: '@+DropDownList/create' is incompatible with attribute id (attr) reference.

C:\Users\MatthewW\AndroidStudioProjects\nfcscanner3\app\src\main\res\layout\pop_up_window.xml:9: AAPT: error: '@+DropDownList/dropDownList' is incompatible with attribute id (attr) reference.

C:\Users\MatthewW\AndroidStudioProjects\nfcscanner3\app\src\main\res\layout\drop_down_list_row.xml:7: error: '@+DropDownList/checkbox' is incompatible with attribute id (attr) reference.
C:\Users\MatthewW\AndroidStudioProjects\nfcscanner3\app\src\main\res\layout\drop_down_list_row.xml:12: error: '@+DropDownList/SelectOption' is incompatible with attribute id (attr) reference.
C:\Users\MatthewW\AndroidStudioProjects\nfcscanner3\app\src\main\res\layout\messagerecipientlayout.xml:15: error: '@+DropDownList/SelectBox' is incompatible with attribute id (attr) reference.
C:\Users\MatthewW\AndroidStudioProjects\nfcscanner3\app\src\main\res\layout\messagerecipientlayout.xml:25: error: '@+DropDownList/create' is incompatible with attribute id (attr) reference.
C:\Users\MatthewW\AndroidStudioProjects\nfcscanner3\app\src\main\res\layout\pop_up_window.xml:9: error: '@+DropDownList/dropDownList' is incompatible with attribute id (attr) reference.
error: failed linking file resources.


> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED
```

Comment: Share your `build.gradle` with question

Comment: @NileshRathod Hi, i've share the build.gradle

Comment: use `implementation` instead of  `compile` and remove `compile files('libs/gcm.jar')` beacuse you have added dependencies for `play-services`

Comment: For the AAPT2 error you need to check the build logs. If you have trouble fining them you can go to the project in a terminal and run "gradlew clean :app:processDebugResources" and the error should be in the std err.

Comment: @NileshRathod i've edited the gradle as in edit2, is that ok?

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska Hi, i've run the command from the terminal but i get the following as i have not installed Jdk but use the embedded java that comes with Android Studio. C:\Users\MatthewW\AndroidStudioProjects\nfcscanner3>gradlew clean :app:processDebugResources

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH. The path to the embedded jre in Android studio is: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre. How can i set the JAVA_HOME when i use an embedded java

Comment: can you set the java_home to point to the embedded java?

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska i'm unsure if i can because i cannot see a jkd1.8.x folder in the Android studio install folder. Years ago i would download Java from Oracle and specify the jdk folder as the JAVA_HOME but in Android studio, it says to use the embedded jre. In that folder and surrounding folders i cannot see a jdk folder. Not sure what to do

Comment: you can just download one from oracle

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska Hi, ok got it working now with a new Java download. I ran the 'gradlew clean :app:processDebugResources' command and the results are in EDIT3. It seems like there are problems in my res dir with checkboxes etc. Do you what i can do to sort it?

Comment: Great! Almost there then. :) Can you show me where you're defining DropDownList and its attributes?

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska Hi Izabela, yeah gettingthere slowly :) I looked at the files in question and replaced android:id="@+DropDownList/SelectOption" with android:id="@+id/DropDownList-SelectOption". It's old code that i had copied from the internet years  ago and didn't conform to having @+id/ and also the second / in the resource name was causing a problem, so i replaced with'-'. I now have a problem with gradlew clean :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac, so i'm just working through those errors. I'll let you know if there is anything i can't fix. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

It's good to get the latest versions. Just there're some concern. In your case, the red line means that **com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable** and **com.android.support:mediarouter-v7** libs are both included in **com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0** and in some 3rd parties (with different verions) you're using. You need to exclude the old ones. The thing is how to determine which libraries to exclude. It's not difficult.

I'll explain my case as example where module **com.android.support:customtabs** was conflicted.

First, we need to list out dependencies with command:

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

You will see a graph like this:

```
+--- io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1
|    \--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6
+--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0 -> 1.1.6
+--- com.github.mmin18:flexlayout:1.2.6
+--- com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:0.1.3
|    +--- com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1
```

In this example, we have a red line with conflicted module **com.android.support:customtabs** because it's both included in **com.android.support** and **com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:0.1.3**. So we need to exclude it from the microsoft module. Just with this config in gradle:

```
implementation('com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:0.1.3') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'customtabs'
}
```

Then just rebuild gradle and the conflict with module **com.android.support:customtabs** would be resolved.
You could apply the same steps with other module.